# for internal method test case method is not accessible

Tags: unit-testing, c#-4.0

I am writing unit test case for my internal method. I have made necessary changes in AssemblyInfo.cs of my mail class project
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("myunitest_assemblyname")]

now i can access my internal method in unit test case method.
but when i compile the code it is giving an error as below

### Error   1   'main class project name' does not contain a definition for 'Process' and no extension method 'Process' accepting a first argument of type 'main class project name' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

my main class has strong name.

it would be great if some one point where i am missing.

main class structure

```
namespace Renewals
{
    public class StateProcessor
    {
        internal virtual void PutEmailInQueue(DataTable dataTable)
        {    
        }
    }
}
```

//test class structure

```
namespace Renewals.Tests.Unit
{
    [TestClass]
    public class StateProcessorTest
    {

        [TestMethod]
        public void PutEmailInQueueTest()
        {
            DateTime processingDate = Convert.ToDateTime("27-feb-2013"); ;

            StateProcessor stateProcess = new StateProcessor(processingDate);
            stateProcess.PutEmailInQueue(new DataTable());
        }
    }
}
```

PutEmailInQueue - this method giving me problem.

Comment: Please post some of your source code.

Comment: update as per your requirement

Comment: Hmm. Where is "Process" referenced?

Comment: i have changed the actual name in above and in error consider 'Process' to 'StateProcessor'.

Comment: Have you tried putting a "using Renewals;" statement in you unit test source file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you wrote that your class use strong name.

I think you have to modify your InternalsVisibleTo() statement with the public key.

e.g.: [assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("friend_signed_B, PublicKey=0024000004800000940000000602000000240000525341310004000001000100e3aedce99b7e10823920206f8e46cd5558b4ec7345bd1a5b201ffe71660625dcb8f9a08687d881c8f65a0dcf042f81475d2e88f3e3e273c8311ee40f952db306c02fbfc5d8bc6ee1e924e6ec8fe8c01932e0648a0d3e5695134af3bb7fab370d3012d083fa6b83179dd3d031053f72fc1f7da8459140b0af5afc4d2804deccb6")]

for more informations see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385180.aspx

Comment: Strong names for InternalsVisibleTo should not be required. It's only needed as a security feature to prevent malicious users from accessing your code with an assembly with the same file name.

Comment: If I do not set the public key I get a compiler error: ´Friend assembly reference <reference> is invalid. Strong-name signed assemblies must specify a public key in their InternalsVisibleTo declarations.´
see also: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763089.aspx

Comment: Ah! I've usually gone the opposite route -- I've had non-signed assemblies reference the signed-assemblies without specifying the key. So, uh -- this is good that it's a compiler error. This humble pie is delicious.